# Django - aggregate queryset by week of year

Tags: python, django, orm

I have model looking like this:

```
class TestData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    one_value = models.IntegerField()
    second_value = models.IntegerField()
    create_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Is any way to easy generate queryset of summed values for every week of year?
Django 1.9, Python 3

Comment: How do you define a week? What have you tried?

Comment: @Sayse My own solution is very ugly. I create additional column 'week' and do year, week, _ = create_at.isocalendar(). Its working but i'm not proud from this part of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Sum

class Week(Func):
    def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
        self.function = 'WEEK'
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

data = (TestData.objects
        .filter(create_at__year=year)
        .annotate(week=Week('create_at', output_field=IntegerField()))
        .values('week')
        .annotate(Sum('one_value')))
```

Or `Sum(F('one_value') + F('second_value'))`, depending on what sum you want to get.

Comment: I never use Func. Can you tell me why when i try do print(data) i get  "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: None"

Comment: @Xezeqeel What database do you use?

Comment: it works for me with such ending of code: return super(Week, self).as_sql(compiler, connection)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Follows on from Vladimir Danilov's solution.

```
class WeekFunc(Func):
        """
            SQL function call for grouping by WEEK
        """
        def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
            self.function = 'WEEK'
            return super(Week, self).as_sql(compiler, connection)


data = queryset.annotate(week=Week('start_time')) \
        .values_list('week') \
        .annotate(some_avg=Avg('field_1')) \
        .order_by('week')
```

Comment: `WeekFunc` or `Week`?

Comment: @LShi you can name it whichever, as long as self.function is 'WEEK'